# for loop before grep getting its output from sed

Tags: bash, for-loop, sed, grep, pipe

I'm trying to use sed for manipulate text from a file, pipe the result to grep but I have for loop before grep, trying this code

```
sed 's/["."",""("")"]//g' file.txt | for i in ${array[@]}; do if grep -q -i "${array[$i]}";  then echo "${array[$i]}" fi
done
```

However the problem is that the output from sed is not being piped to sed (through the for loop)

only this works well:

```
for i in ${array[@]}; do
sed 's/["."",""("")"]//g' file.txt | if grep -q -i "${array[$i]}";  then echo "${array[$i]}"
fi
```

done

but the sed command here is redundant in the loop.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Please post input data (file.txt array) and, what you like to get out of it and what rules.

Comment: Many things look wrong here: `["."",""("")"]` is weird; `for i in ${array[@]}` followed by `${array[$i]}` is bizarre; using `grep` could be replaced with Bash pattern matching; using `sed` could be replaced with Bash parameter expansion. Please follow Jotne's advice and post exactly what you're trying to achieve (including the content of `file.txt` and `array`).

Comment: Any time you write a loop in shell just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach. Post sample input and expected output so we can help you do whatever it is you're trying to do the right way.

Answer (score 0):

The first run through your loop is eating all the sed output

to solve that save the output in a variable and replay it for each loop:

```
words=`sed 's/["."",""("")"]//g' file.txt`
for i in ${array[@]}
do 
  if echo "$words" | grep -q -i "${array[$i]}"
  then
     echo "${array[$i]}"
  fi
done
```